# Ionic5 item vertical alignment

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I am trying to align all items in the `ion-row` that they appear in the same row. Below is my code and screenshot. The button is too large and pushes under the text font. I need the button text to align with the other text. How?[image]

I've tried a few things I found online but nothing seems to work:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row justify-content-center align-items-center>
    <ion-col size="8" justify-content-center align-items-center>
      <b>{{spotName}}</b>&nbsp;Surfed {{numberSessions}}x
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="2" justify-content-center align-items-center>
      <ion-button size="small">Add</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col size="2" justify-content-center align-items-center>
      More
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
...
```

Comment: you are using attributes. like `justify-content-center` and `align-items-center`. in ionic 4+ attributes are deprecated use them in class. go to ionic documentation css utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Had to add `ion-row class="ion-align-items-center"`

Comment: Also u can use table instead of column. When use table, all things center horizontally.